# Adding @NoArgsConstructor anotationg causes error

Tags: java, spring, lombok

I have a Student class that needs a default constructor, I want to add it with the @NoArgsConstructor annotation the problem is that when I add it all my variables give an error "Variable 'xxx' might not have been initialized"

This is the class

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.*;

import java.util.UUID;
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor

@Entity
public class Student {


    private final UUID studentId;
    private final String firstName;
    private final String lastName;
    private final String email;
    private final Gender gender;




    public Student(
              @JsonProperty("studentId") UUID studentId
            , @JsonProperty("firstName")String firstName
            , @JsonProperty("lastName")String lastName
            , @JsonProperty("email")String email
            ,@JsonProperty("gender") Gender gender) {
        this.studentId = studentId;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;

        this.email = email;
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student{" +
                "studentId=" + studentId +
                ", firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
                ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                ", gender=" + gender +
                '}';
    }

    enum Gender{
        MALE,FEMALE,male,female
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you see that with a no-args constructor the fields in your object indeed won't be initialised? Look at their declaration. Do you see why they must be initialised by a constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the fields in your class are `final` and are **expected to be initialised when an instance of object is created** and not changed. When you use `@NoArgsConstructor` you are creating a constructor that can be used to create the object **without initialising the values**. If you want an object to be created without values you can remove the final keyword as follows:

```
    private UUID studentId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private Gender gender;
```

If you want the values to be assigned during object creation remove `@NoArgsConstructor`.